# How to create a reference in a many-to-many relationship with transact SQL?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, relations

I am creating my first database using only code (I don't like to use graphical interfaces, I feel that I am not learning to write T-SQL code, it is my personal opinion), **I do not know how to create the reference between my `master tables`**

In theory it is a database to be able to carry out inventories that are in different companies

my boards are:

`Inventory`

`assets`

I Created an intermediate `Inventory_Asset` table to be able to create multiple asset records in a company's inventory, and a company can have multiple inventories.

**Inventory**

```sql
-- TABLE INVENTORY
GO
CREATE TABLE Inventory
(
    [inventory_id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [company_id] INT,
    [name] VARCHAR(50),
    [observations] VARCHAR(500),
    [date_created] DATETIME DEFAULT(GETDATE()),
    CONSTRAINT PK_INVENTORY PRIMARY KEY (inventory_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_INVENTORY_COMPANY FOREIGN KEY(company_id) REFERENCES Company(company_id)
)
```

**Asset**

```sql
-- TABLE ASSET
GO
CREATE TABLE Asset
(
    [asset_id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [assettype_id] INT,
    [assetcategory_id] INT,
    [assetmadeby_id] INT,
    [code] INT,
    [model_name] VARCHAR(50),
    [model_number] VARCHAR(50),
    [serial_number] VARCHAR(30),
    [price] DECIMAL(10,2),
    CONSTRAINT PK_ASSET_ID PRIMARY KEY(asset_id),
    CONSTRAINT UQ_ASSET_CODE UNIQUE(code)
)
```

**Inventory_Asset**

```sql
--TABLE INVENTORY_ASSET
CREATE TABLE Inventory_Asset
(
    asset_id INT,
    inventory_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT PK_INVENTORY_ASSET PRIMARY KEY (asset_id,inventory_id)
)
```

I accept criticism and suggestions. I want to learn :)

Comment: Read about foreign keys (a.k.a. referential integrity constraints).

Comment: "_I don't like to use graphical interfaces, I feel that I am not learning to write T-SQL code_" If you are using SQL Server Management Studio, you can often use wizard to setup action, but instead of running it by clicking _OK_, you can use _Script_ button near the top, to generate SQL code that does the action you want. I think it's sometimes useful trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have foreign key in your inventory table (referencing company table), so I am going to assume you want to add foreign key to already existing table. You can do that like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Inventory_Asset
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Inventory_Asset_asset
FOREIGN KEY (asset_id) REFERENCES dbo.Asset (asset_id)
```